# Delete everything in a folder that doesn't have a tag in Mavericks

Tags: osx-mavericks

How can I delete everything in a folder that doesn't have a tag? Manually sifting through it is fairly unreasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mdfind 'kMDItemUserTags!=*' -onlyin . -0|xargs -0 rm
```

Or using [tag](https://github.com/jdberry/tag):

```
find . -type f|while read f;do [[ $(tag -m \* "$f") ]]||rm "$f";done
```